# using ifelse in renderDataTable (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

```
 #server

tables <- reactiveValues(XVALUES=data.frame(),
                     YVALUES=data.frame())

output$userinput <- renderDataTable({

  if(input$name=="X" &  input$city=="BOS" & (is.data.frame(tables$XVALUES) && nrow(tables$XVALUES)!=0)){
      cbind(data.frame(Serial=seq(1:5)),tables$XVALUES)}
  else if(input$name=="X" &  input$city=="BOS" & (is.data.frame(tables$XVALUES) && nrow(tables$XVALUES)==0)){}
  else if (input$name=="Y" & input$city=="NYC"  & (is.data.frame(tables$YVALUES) && nrow(tables$YVALUES)!=0)){
    cbind(data.frame(Serial=seq(1:5)),tables$YVALUES)}
  else if (input$name=="Y" & input$city=="NYC"  & (is.data.frame(tables$YVALUES) && nrow(tables$YVALUES)==0)){}

})
```

based on two user inputs I create and display a new data frame by adding a additional **Serial** column to the XVALUES or YVALUES dataframe. The issue is that even if the XVALUES/YVALUES dataframe is empty it still displays the serial column. I want nothing to be displayed if the XVALUES data frame is empty. where am I going wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce that error. The table is empty on my machine. Here is what I typed in

```
server = function( input, output, session ){
  tables <- reactiveValues(XVALUES=data.frame(),
                           YVALUES=data.frame())

  output$userinput <- renderDataTable({
    if(input$name=="X" &  input$city=="BOS" & (is.data.frame(tables$XVALUES) && 
      nrow(tables$XVALUES)!=0)){
      cbind(data.frame(Serial=seq(1:5)),tables$XVALUES)}
    else if(input$name=="X" &  input$city=="BOS" & (is.data.frame(tables$XVALUES) && 
       nrow(tables$XVALUES)==0)){}
    else if (input$name=="Y" & input$city=="NYC"  & (is.data.frame(tables$YVALUES) && 
      nrow(tables$YVALUES)!=0)){
      cbind(data.frame(Serial=seq(1:5)),tables$YVALUES)}
    else if (input$name=="Y" & input$city=="NYC"  & (is.data.frame(tables$YVALUES) && 
       nrow(tables$YVALUES)==0)){}
  })
}

ui = fluidPage(
  selectInput("name","name",c("X","Y")),
  selectInput("city","city",c("BOS","NYC")),
  dataTableOutput("userinput")
)

shinyApp( ui, server )
```